# Django, как отправить аргумент в handler404?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-3.5

Как при переопределении ошибки 404 отправить в функцию аргументы?

Нужно отравить аргумент `error` и `text`

```
# views.py
def handler404(request, error, text):
    response = render_to_response('error/40X.html', {'error': error, 'text':text})
    response.status_code = error
    return response
```

И код переопределения ошибки 404:

```
handler404 = 'app.views.handler404'
```

Использую Django v1.10 и Python v3.5, и не очень хочется создавать функцию под каждую ошибку.

Comment: Откуда будут передаваться text и error?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev нужно передать из mysite/urls.py где задан `handler404 = 'app.views.handler404'`, возможно есть другой способ задания уникальной страницы для HTTP ошибок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не думаю что нужно использовать `handler404`. Django `page_not_found` делает то, что вы хотите.

В Django 1.9+ можно включить `{{ exception }}` в 404 шаблоне.

На ваш взгляд, можно было бы установить сообщение при поднятии исключения, например:

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
    raise Http404('custom error message')
```

Не имеет смысла добавлять `response.status_code` в `handler404`  если всегда код ответа будет 404.

> Перевод ответа с [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871189/django-how-to-send-a-argument-in-handler404) от [@alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair)